# Autocomplete textbox collection

Tags: c#, textbox, autocomplete, autocompletebox

In windows forms a textbox can be made into an autocomplete textbox by giving it a simple list of strings or by giving it a custom source that can only be a
AutoCompleteCollection which is a strong typed list of strings. 
I would like to be able to add a key to each string..so that whenever any suggestion is selected I can grab that key.

I might just be drawing a blank..but does anyone have a suggestion ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: i thought i could inherit from the AutoCompleteCollection  and reimplement the add and get, but i can only override toString, getHashCode and Equals....

Comment: If you're responding to Josh's answer, you should post it on his answer.  As to your comment though, you can implement another method with the same name but different parameters to overload it.  You can only override virtual members, but you can always overload.

Comment: You don't need to "reimplement" (override). Instead you add an overload. This method does not replace the existing Add method that takes one parameter, it adds an additional Add method that takes 2 parameters. See my example in my answer.

Comment: yeah, i posted the comment before looking at your answer, i see what you mean now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class AutoCompleteStringCollection is not sealed so you could certainly derive from it and create an overload of Add that takes two parameters: a key and a value.

Then you can track that in a dictionary. You'll have to store the string twice (once in the base class's collection and once in your dictionary) but you can then add a lookup method like so:

```
class KeyedAutoCompleteStringCollection : AutoCompleteStringCollection {

    private readonly Dictionary<string,string> keyedValues =
        new Dictionary<string,string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

    public void Add(string value, string key) {
        base.Add(value);
        keyedValues.Add(value, key); // intentionally backwards
    }

    public string Lookup(string value) {
        string key;
        if (keyedValues.TryGetValue(value, out key)) {
            return key;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the value in the text box (which can be auto suggested) to have an associated value.  You could do that by creating a `Dictionary<string, string>` with the `TextBox` text as the key and what you are calling the 'key' as the value.  Whenever you want to locate the 'key' for a particular `TextBox` value, you can check the dictionary for it.

Of course, a `TextBox` may not be the best way to represent your data if there must be a key.  If there must be a key, the `ComboBox` (with `DropDownStyle` set to `ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList`) might be a better option.